# Best strategy for connecting from my client to my database

Tags: wpf, database, silverlight, web-services, architecture

Im looking into developing a new version of a client/server application for a client. The current solution is a website in asp.net mvc.

The purpose of the application is to build a digital signage solution, this means that on the client the user will be creating playlists, from viedos and images and scheduling them to be shown on a screen. The items to be displayed are WPF user controls, one with logic for image and one for logic about video.

The current application is web based and accesses the central database directly. When all the clients (the ones that present the information) request data it is done through a webservice. The customer is very happy to use the web based client, although they request more "rich" behavior. This includes a principal requirement og having a preview of both a single "slide" and of a collection of slides.

I started developing this as a WPF application (discarding silverlight because of the preview of a wpf user control). Now im faced with the problem/challenge of defining how to access the database. The customers probably want the same usage pattern as they have now, where they move around with their labtops and thus not being on the same network as the database all the time.

My question is this: How do I design the database connectivity layer, should i go for pure web service based so everybody always use this, or should i make some kind of disconnected mode, where they can work at home, then connect and synchronize their data? Should i require them to be on the same network as the databse, so i can connect directly using a database layer and a connectionstring?

Will a webservice based approach be fast enough for working with images, videos (thinking about only loading thumbnails of these, else data would kill the performance ~several Gb og data). Im planning on using thumbnails on the clients and when on the home network they connect and get all the big videos and images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing your app it's worthwhile to remember the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) principles, and to be wary of overkill solutions and premature optimizations.

If I understand correctly, you have a working web-app, in which the only further feature which is required is a slideshow of sorts.
you can find lots of jQuery (or any other web-client framework) solutions for that.

If, nevertheless, you decide to develop a new client- you already have a webservice which is working well! I would suggest using it.

About the idea of storing the data on the client side- that's a classic candidate for YAGNI; Test your application's performance, and then see if you need anything more sophisticated like caching on the client side etc.

A side note- having the client application access the DB directly is not a recommended approach; it effectively cancels the 'server' part of 'client-server', and causes a high coupling between your presentation and business logic / data access.
It would be better to have a WCF application on the server which is responsible for fetching the requested files.

Comment: Thanks, ill disconnect the client from the database. yeah KISS and YAGNI should never be forgotten - i sometimes fall into this, thinking too far ahead